# File or content-type-association issue Windows 10

Tags: windows-explorer, content-type-association

I am running Windows 10 1909 19H2 (Build 18363.2274). This problem just started a few days ago and I have no restore points to go back to.

*The Problem:* I can no longer click on a folder in file explorer to open another folder. When I click on any folder, it says there is nothing associated with it. So it is like something is messed up with the association for a folder. I see no way to fix it. I looked in the default apps section and don't see anything for a folder. I tried to reset all to Microsoft default, but it did not help. I also ran SFC /SCANNOW.

So currently I can NOT access any folder at all through file explorer. As a test, I installed a 3rd party file explorer ( DirOpus ), and **now I can** enter any folder but **ONLY** through this 3rd party explorer replacement. File Explorer still will not open a folder.

[image: left click on any folder]

[image: right click then left click properties]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the registry, all of those associations are defined. I'm not sure which one of them got screwed up and by what, but you can try to reset them by importing a clean default set of those keys/values.

You can do it using the files from [**File Association Fixes for Windows 10 (Defaults)**](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/file-association-fixes-windows-10/)

- Download the ones for **Folder** and for **Directory** (both are related to folders, not sure which one is the one, but I don't think it can hurt much to do both)
- Extract the **.reg** file from the downloaded ZIP archive
- Right-click the REG file and choose Merge. (Alternately, you can open the Registry Editor and then using the Import option from the File menu, to merge the REG file contents.) *Note that you need to be an administrator to apply these fixes

(Here is a backup download location of those files: [**Directory**](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao8EzDmtlA0Jj0_IpRtBMS6jABbQ?e=VaLbTR), [**Folder**](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao8EzDmtlA0Jj1CqCYMN8TvoJ9BJ?e=jgctgj).)